# Linq to SQL: .FirstOrDefault() not applicable to select new { ... }

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201686/linq-to-sql-select-optimization). Which lead me to a new question :)

Up until this point, I have used the following pattern of selecting stuff with Linq to SQL, with the purpose of being able to handle 0 "rows" returned by the query:

```
var person = (from p in [DataContextObject].Persons
              where p.PersonsID == 1
              select new p).FirstOrDefault();

if (person == null)
{
    // handle 0 "rows" returned.
}
```

But I can't use `FirstOrDefault()` when I do:

```
var person = from p in [DataContextObject].Persons
             where p.PersonsID == 1
             select new { p.PersonsID, p.PersonsAdress, p.PersonsZipcode };

// Under the hood, this pattern generates a query which selects specific
// columns which will be faster than selecting all columns as the above
// snippet of code does. This results in a performance-boost on large tables.
```

How do I check for 0 "rows" returned by the query, using the second pattern?




**UPDATE:**

I think my build fails because I am trying to assign the result of the query to a variable (`this._user`) declared with the type of `[DataContext].User`.

```
this._user = (from u in [DataContextObject].Users
              where u.UsersID == [Int32]
              select new { u.UsersID }).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Compilation error: Cannot implicitly convert type "AnonymousType#1" to "[DataContext].User".*

Any thoughts on how I can get around this? Would I have to make my own object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your UPDATE: you have to either create your own type, change this._user to be *int*, or select the whole object, not only specific columns.

Answer (score 13):

Why can you keep doing the samething?  Is it giving you an error?

```
var person = (from p in [DataContextObject].Persons
              where p.PersonsID == 1
              select new { p.PersonsID, p.PersonsAdress, p.PersonsZipcode }).FirstOrDefault();

if (person == null) {    
    // handle 0 "rows" returned.
}
```

It is still a reference object just like you actual object, it is just anonymous so you don't know the actual type before the code is compiled.

Comment: Agreed, the above should work, unless there's an unrelated runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

> I see now what you were *actually* asking!  Sorry, my answer no longer applies.  I thought you were not getting a null value when it was empty. The accepted response is correct, if you want to use the object out of scope, you need to create a new type and just use New MyType(...).  I know DevEx's RefactorPro has a refactoring for this, and I think resharper does as well.

Call .FirstOrDefault(null) like this:

```
string[] names = { "jim", "jane", "joe", "john", "jeremy", "jebus" };
var person = (
    from p in names where p.StartsWith("notpresent") select 
        new { Name=p, FirstLetter=p.Substring(0,1) } 
    )
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    .FirstOrDefault();

MessageBox.Show(person==null?"person was null":person.Name + "/" + person.FirstLetter);
```

That does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (person.Any()) /* ... */;
```

OR

```
if (person.Count() == 0) /* ... */;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `FirstOrDefault`.  Just have

```
var PersonFields = (...).FirstOrDefault()
```

PersonFields will be be null or an object with those properties you created.